# "А волны и стонут(,) и плачут(,) и плещут о борт корабля..."

Tags: пунктуация

Все, думаю, помнят эту песню. Но вот у меня вопрос: нужны ли тут запятые? Тут интонационно я перечисления не слышу, но могу ошибаться. А что скажут специалисты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А волны и стонут и плачут, и плещут о борт корабля. Два первых глагола близки по значению, поэтому  связаны союзом И, а далее предложение строится на повторяющихся союзах И...И, здесь есть перечисление и соответствующая интонация. Получаем: А волны и (стонут и плачут), и плещут о борт корабля.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ.
Меня вот что удивляет: мы каждый раз решаем задачки так, будто никто и никогда с обсуждаемой  проблемой не сталкивался, а мы в теме просто первопроходцы, берем на себя огромную ответственность за каждый шаг и слово. В действительности же все варианты давно изучены, потому что их не так уж много в языке. В приведенном примере достаточно узнать конструкцию, которую условно можно назвать 2+1, она во многих учебниках рассматривается.

Например:Он прошёл (огонь и воду) и медные трубы. На огромном расстоянии разлёгся город  и (тихо пламенел и сверкал разноцветными огнями).И стали они (жить да поживать)  да добра наживать.

А вот примеры, где ставятся две запятые, там нет тесного единства слов:Колесо чугунное вертится, и гудит, и ветром обдаёт. Океан приносил блестящую раковину, или морского ежа, или красивый коралл. Нет, пусть послужит в армии, да потянет лямку, да будет солдат, а не шаматон.

И читаются эти варианты по-разному: при тесной первых двух слов между ними паузы нет, они составляют единую фразу, в противном же случае мы имеем перечислительную интонацию с паузами между словами.

Comment: У автора( Н.Букина) вообще-то обе запятые.http://www.cartalana.ru/pes-road-03.php 
Я и в своём песеннике(советской поры)посмотрела, тоже 2 запятые - по общим правилам при повторяющихся союзах.

Comment: Я бы тоже две запятые поставил. Ну или одну последнюю. 
См. мой ответ.

Comment: А волны и стонут, и плачут.  Так? Добавляю. А волны и стонут, и плачут, и бьются...

Comment: >А волны и стонут, и плачут. Так? Добавляю. А волны и стонут, и плачут, и бьются...  
  
Я бы написал именно так. Запятые перед "и плачут" и "и бьются" очевидны. А вот что касается первого И... Я даже не соображу, может ли быть для неё хоть какая-то мотивировка.

Answer (score 2):

> Два первых глагола близки по значению

И именно поэтому логично предположить, что оба И перед ними - усилительные частицы или повторяющиеся союзы. А третье - И обычный союз.
**А волны (и стонут, и плачут) и плещут о борт корабля.**
Но такая конструкция вряд ли встретит понимание редактора.
Они люди весьма консервативные.
Поэтому все-таки - две запятые.

Answer (score 0):

Склоняюсь к одной запятой, согласна с объяснением!